# writing data to an xml file from a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write data in a list to an xml file using the following code,i have the expected output on how the data should be present in data.xml file...running into a compilation error,can anyone provide inputs on what is wrong here?

```
data = [['SEC.12.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC', '\\\\ftp\\location'], ['SEC.13.0', '\\\\DATA\\LOC2', '\\\\ftp\\location2']]


for set in data :
    f = open('data.xml', 'w')
    f.write(<pro>set[0]</pro>)
    f.write(<dataloc>set[1]</dataloc>)
    f.write(<ftploc>set[2]</ftploc>)
```

error:-

```
  File "test.py", line 8
    f.write(<pro>set[0]</pro>)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
data.xml file should contain the follwing

        <pro>SEC.12.0</pro>
        <dataloc>\\DATA\LOC</dataloc>
        <ftploc>\\ftp\location</ftploc>
        <pro>SEC.13.0</pro>
        <dataloc>\\DATA\LOC2</dataloc>
        <ftploc>\\ftp\location2</ftploc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing strings to `.write()`:

```
f.write('<pro>' + set[0] + '</pro>')
```

`set` is a built-in function, so don't shadow it by naming your variable `set`. Also, if you're going to be creating any non-trivial XML, use an XML library like [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: is there a better way to implement the above?

Comment: @user2125827: By constructing the XML using one of the two libraries that I linked to. The first one should have a few examples.

Comment: i couldnt find any examples,anything am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to f.write (e.g., `f.write("<pro>%s</pro>" % (set[0]))`).

Side note, avoid naming your variables "set" since it is a built-in type.

Comment: set[0] is not being deciphered..and also output is not as expected..its in a one-line like "<pro>set[0]</pro><dataloc>set[1]</dataloc><ftploc>set[2]</ftploc>"

Comment: Sorry. Noticed my mistake. The updated version should be correct.

Comment: is there a way to append new line after every write without adding a new f.write("\n")

Comment: @user2125827 on python 2 you can use `print >>f, 'text'. On python 3 you use the print function and specify the file.